# data structure for objects with unique/auto-increment IDs in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm searching for a way to deal with a list of objects that should have unique IDs in Javascript. I want to be able to add, remove and edit (by their ID) objects that are in this list, loop over the list and be able to store it in a JSON file.
My naive implementation looks like this: `[6,{"ID":4,"name":"test"},{"ID":5,"name":"test2"}]`
Each time I add an object to the array I give it the number that is in position `[0]` as an ID and increase the number in position `[0]`.
As I thought about how to edit an element in this kind of data structure (my ideas were using `indexOf()` or an ordinary `for`) I started to wonder whether my data structure was really the best way to solve my problem.

My question: Is there a better data structure/way of dealing with objects in JavaScript that fulfills my requirements?

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Read the ID of the last member, and increment that for the next ID to add. That way you can get rid of the index member.

Comment: When it comes to selecting one of the objects to edit it, what is the criteria? Would you know its ID, or...?

Comment: @nnnnnn I would know their ID, yes.

Comment: @Teemu Good idea, thank you!

Comment: OK, so `.indexOf()` wouldn't work to find an item. It might be nicer to use an object rather than an array, so that you can immediately select by ID without searching - maybe something like: `var data = { nextID : 6, items: { 4: {"ID":4,"name":"test"}, 5: {"ID":5,"name":"test2"} }}`. Then given an ID in a variable `id` you could say `data.items[id]` to grab that object. You could add a method that returns the next ID, or a method that lets you add an item and automatically assigns the next ID, etc.

Comment: @nnnnnn Also a good idea, thank you. Coming from Java I also thought that a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) could be a good idea. What do you think?

Comment: A `Map` could work, but I haven't really used them yet due to insufficient browser support. But even a plain object can be used in a map-esque manner for your requirements, and you can easily add some helper methods to the object to handle adding and removing items. (When storing it in JSON it wouldn't store the methods, just the actual data.)

Comment: If the platform you're developing for supports it, definitely go for a `Map`.

Comment: Or you can create [a host object](https://jsfiddle.net/jqcy5a2e/), which would take care of all you need.

Comment: nnnnnn, jcaron, Teemu (as apparently only one user can be mentioned with "@"): Thank you for your help, you're awesome! I'll play around a bit and then decide which implementation I'm going to go with.